Non determinism problem in TensorFlow 2.16.1
I'm using tensorflow v.2.16.1 and I'm encountering this error
GPU MaxPool gradient ops do not yet have a deterministic XLA implementation
when setting
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
I noticed also an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/69417
Anyone solved this problem? Thanks for any help
I switched on CPU and clearly the error didn't appear.

It's an identified an open issue. Just wait until the developers fix it or you can fix it yourself and create a merge request to the repository.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/69417#issuecomment-2387147015

In earlier Keras versions (Keras 2 or tf-keras), the compile method had jit_compile=None, meaning XLA compilation was not used by default. However, Keras 3 defaults to jit_compile="auto", attempting to use XLA for improved performance. In some cases, this can lead to an error. To avoid this error, explicitly set jit_compile=False when compiling your model in Keras 3. And consider using the latest version of tensorflow.
